# AS3 - Overriding a class setter that doesn't exist?

Tags: actionscript-3, setter

I'm following a tutorial about OOP and setters/getters and overrides in AS3.
In the tutorial, we have created a class that `extends` a `sprite` to act as a button that contains a `shape` and a `textfield`.

The tutorial author demonstrates that if you use the `height` property of the class (inherited all the way up from `DisplayObject` like so:

```
button.height = 100;
```

then not only will the `shape` of the button be scaled up, but also the `textfield` and the font in it will also be scaled up to be larger. The author doesn't want this, he wants only the `shape` to be scaled up, while leaving the font size the way it is. He does this in the following way:

```
override public function set height(h:Number):void {
// Custom code here.
}
```

This is making me confused, because having looked closely at Adobe's AS3 API reference, I cannot see any `method` that sets the `DisplayObject`'s height. I can only see a `property` for `height`.

Before getting into `override` the author does explain `setters and getters`, so I understand the concept. However, I cannot understand how you can `override` a `setter` that doesn't seem to exist?
I would have assumed that to be able to override anything that anything has to be there in the first place.

If somebody could explain this technique I would be very grateful, or maybe point me to some more reading on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A property is not always a public variable. In fact, `DisplayObject`'s `height` property has both a setter and a getter function, thus a setter exists and can be overridden.

Comment: But these are hidden from public view? Where can I see `all` of a class's methods and properties?

Comment: No, they are not hidden. Check [this manual](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html), find "height" property, follow downwards and look for "implementation". You'll see there's a setter and a getter.

Comment: In fact this site has a (nearly) complete documentation on classes in AS3, and it's an official one. So, surf there. I use it all the time when I need to look up something.

Comment: Ohhh, there it is! I didn't see that there! Thanks :)